# Search bug in angular 2: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging

In the project, when user search for "employee" he should be redirected on the Profile-page of searched "employee".

Problem appear in the ngOnInit method of component ProfilesResult:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadItemElementTemplate().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(x => {
        this.itemElement = x;
    });
    this.activatedRoute.params.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(params => {
        let profileId = params['id'];
        if (profileId) {
            this.profileIdQueryParam = profileId;
        }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.profileIdScroll = this.profileIdQueryParam;
    })
    console.log("Profile results ngOnInit");
}
```

This are method which is called into "ngOnInit()":

1. `

   ```
   private loadItemElementTemplate() {
     return this.dataService.loadActionWidget(this.path).map((data: any) => {
       let itemElement: UiElement = JSON.parse(data.Data.WidgetJson);
       return itemElement;
    });
   }`


   loadActionWidget(path: string) {
     return this.requests.get(environment.actionWidgetDefinitionUrl + path,      
       this.options, null);
    }

    get(url: string, options: RequestOptions, params: any): Observable<any> 
     {
       return this.http.get(url, options)
         .map((res: any) => res.json())
         .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()) || 'Server 
          error');
     }



    NgOnInit of profile-result.component.ts 
       ngOnInit(): void {    
      this.loadItemElementTemplate().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
       .subscribe(x => {
         this.itemElement = x;
       });
       this.activatedRoute.params.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
         .subscribe(params => {
            let profileId = params['id'];
          if (profileId) {
             this.profileIdQueryParam = profileId;
          }
        });
         setTimeout(() => {
            this.profileIdScroll = this.profileIdQueryParam;
         })
          console.log("Profile results ngOnInit");
        }
   ```

**ERROR:**
[image: Error in console]

Comment: why are you sending the path as query string? you need to use encodeURIComponent() to encode the path as string before sending

Comment: Can you share the `this.dataService.loadActionWidget` method?

Comment: Hey, I added loadActionWidget  and get methods. 
I don't know on send a path on the other way. This way worked in the past.

Comment: can you try replacing backslash with forward slash in your path ?

Comment: for example "widgets/ContactCentre/" etc

Comment: I tried and the problem is same: http://prntscr.com/hk98hq

Comment: You thing the problem is in path?

Comment: Sry just sec I will update with new details post, actually in NgOnInit method of the other component (profiles-result.component.ts) is problem. I will update post.

Comment: the problem might be the value of `environment.actionWidgetDefinitionUrl` which should be like `"https://uat-api.procampaign.com/configuration"` only. The api path that you are using for GET request does not look valid. You should also use the forward slashes

Comment: What is the correct api url that you are trying to access via  `return this.http.get(url, options)`

Comment: Here is the "correct" url/api from enviroment.ts:
actionWidgetDefinitionUrl: "https://uat-api.procampaign.com
/configuration/Widgets/Path?path=" 

Maybe I should try with encodeURIComponent()?

Comment: are you sure the api accepts a url as a querystring parameter `path=` ? you can try with encodeURIComponent() ... but i am not sure how the path is handled at the api . Can you post the api code?